# Custom ImageView to be square

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

i was trying to set a imageview height and width to the width of the screen(Square). The imageview is in a listview. I tried to set the height and width in the getview method of my baseadapter. What happened is that scroll becomes very slow. So what i tried to do is write my own imageview by extending the ImageView class so it will be drawn to the right size so i don't need to change it in the getview method. This still does not change anything. The scrolling is still very slow. how can i set the imageview width and height to match the screen width?

```
     public class ScaledImageView  extends ImageView{

public ScaledImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public ScaledImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public ScaledImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


      @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

   // int width = getMeasuredWidth();



    setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize(this.getMeasuredWidth(), widthMeasureSpec),      resolveSize(this.getMeasuredWidth(), widthMeasureSpec));

}
```

}

Comment: You could try dynamically setting your view size using ImageView image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY); to scale it to your screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    final int width = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(),widthMeasureSpec);
    if(width>this.squareWidth)
    {
        this.squareWidth = width;
    }
    setMeasuredDimension(this.squareWidth, this.squareWidth);
}
```

See my full example at [here](https://github.com/fsiu/dw2020/blob/master/dw2020/src/main/java/net/darkwire/example/widgets/view/SquareImageView.java).

You can also take a look at my adapter to see how I achieve that performance.  I'm guessing you might also be instantiating new Views in you getView().

If it is still slow, I'd need to see your adapter (please also mention the binary size of your images).  Also please see my example, it is super fast even pulling images over the wire and recropping/sizing them.

Comment: @frederick_c_siu- it is still slow.